# JavaScript user-defined sub function syntax

Tags: javascript

I need to read in the parameters in the bracket and perform the spherical to cartesian calculations in the function below. I know this won't work but since I'm new to JavaScript I don't know the technical term for this. Does anyone know what is the correct way and give me some hint so I can find the doc to read online?

```
var v = scene.data.view.displacement(v0.x, v0.y, v0.z, t / 5);
```

The function is a user-defined function and need to perform the calculations below:

```
function displacement(x, y, z, t) {
    var r = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
    var theta = Math.acos(z / r);
    var phi = Math.atan2(y, x);

    return new THREE.Vector3(3 * Math.cos(phi) * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(r - t) / r, 3 * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(r - t) / r, 3 * Math.cos(theta) * Math.sin(r - t) / r);
    }
}
```

Comment: scene.data.view = function displacement(x,y,x){} then call it

Comment: If you already have `scene.data.view` object then you can create a function using `scene.data.view.displacement = function(x, y, z, t) { ... }`.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev,  you mean define: scene.data.view.displacement = function  (x, y, z, t) {} first, and then call var v = scene.data.view.displacement(v0.x, v0.y, v0.z, t / 5)?

Comment: @Victor Yeah, it should work. You define function and then use this function with specified arguments and get calculated result into your `v` variable. If it doens't, then please reproduce this problem at JSFiddle.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Thanks! I defined scene as a global variable but still got "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined." Guess I need to fix something else.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, https://jsfiddle.net/hzhang307/0y1h5z2n/ added

Comment: @Victor `scene` variable is not initialized at all. In addition to declaring variable you need to initialize it with a value. I am not sure what library you are using, so can't tell how exactly it should be initialized.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, I initialized scene actually: scene = new THREE.Scene(); but still thanks for helping me look into this!